# The meaning of "seven’s sixteen and a half"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> “That’s what Mother Gunga thinks, is it,” he said, reading. “Keep cool, young ’un. We’ve got all our work cut out for us. Let’s see. Muir wired half an hour ago: ‘Floods on the Ramgunga. Look out.’ Well, that gives us—one, two—nine and a half for the flood to reach Melipur Ghaut and **seven’s sixteen and a half** to Lataoli—say fifteen hours before it comes down to us.”

This is from ["The Bridge Builders" by Rudyard Kipling](https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/the-bridge-builders.htm).

I don't understand the meaning of "seven’s sixteen and a half".

Answer (score 50):

The character is doing math and saying it out loud. Here, "*and seven's*" means "*plus seven is*", as in, nine and a half hours plus seven hours makes sixteen and a half hours before the flooding reaches Lataoli.

9.5 + 7 = 16.5

Comment: Good answer. I think it would improve the answer to clarify that "seven's" in this case is a contraction of "seven is" and not the possessive form of "seven"

Comment: @Kevin That isn't clear in my second sentence?

Comment: To a native speaker? Most definitely. To a non-native speaker, especially based on the title of the question, possibly not.

Comment: @gotube you were given birth in Canada, so it is typical for you.